# Ubuntu Server - Is something wrong with the 32 Bit version of it?

Tags: 14.04, server, 64-bit, 32-bit

I want to set up my very first server (yay) and I chose Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS (Trusty Tahr) for it because I have used it a little as Desktop software.

I'm using an old PC for this Server with an 32 Bit (AMD86) architecture.

I'm a bit confused about the Ubuntu versions. The website says that the LTS version is 64 bit only even tho I was able to locate a 32 bit version of this version in the 14.04 release notes. (see images)

[image: *image of 64 bit only*]
[image: *image of both 32 and 64 bit*]
<sub>claims 64 bit only: [www.ubuntu.com/download/server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server)

provides both 32 and 64 bit[www.releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/](http://www.releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/)</sub>

Why does the one page says that there's only a 64 bit version of it?

Is something wrong with the 32 Bit version?
Should I be aware of something special?

I hope that you guys can help me. Thank you

Comment: It's just that most people have 64-bit computers, so the 64-bit version is usually best. Click the `Alternative downloads and torrents` below the `Download` button.

Comment: i have a server running on the 32bit version. no problems so far.

Comment: Already burned the 32bit ver on disk and I'm currently installing. Of course we're not living in the 2000 anymore but I don't think that this is enough reason for ubuntu.net to lie to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with Ubuntu 14.04.3 32-bit server.

You can download it by clicking "Alternative downloads...".

The 64-bit version of Ubuntu Server is recommended and it is commonly used. That is why the primary link leads to the 64-bit version.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe they're only going to support the 64-bit LTS version till 2019? I don't know.. doesn't sound particularly likely. AFAIK the 64-bit one will handle memory above 4Gb better but, other than that, there's little practical difference in day to day use.

Comment: Not the case.  64-bit is recommended moreso than 32-bit, to the point that 32-bit is almost considered an 'alternative' architecture - most servers nowadays are 64bit

Comment: Well, I didn't say it wasn't, did I ;) I always use 64-bit servers. I was just trying to think of a reason why the wording was slightly confused.